# I get these errors when I do "npm start", what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, mern

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\User\Desktop\memories_project\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\memories_project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

I tried npm start and i got these errors

Answer (score 2):

Check for `package.json` file exists in the current project `C:\Users\User\Desktop\memories_project`;
If it doesn't exist, you need to create it

```
npm init -y
```

Then make sure when you execute command `npm run start`,
you should have `start` property in `scripts` object:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node your_main_file.js"
}
```

Before starting your project make sure you install all your dependencies by using the command:

```
npm install
```

Comment: i tried it and now i get this ->
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

Comment: You got a new error, good at least some progress. see I've updated the answer!

Comment: now i get this 
> memories_project@1.0.0 start
> node index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\memories_project\index.js'

Comment: You just need to install all dependencies, check out the answer I've updated it!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are in the `directory` of the project, then run `npm install` and finally try to run `npm run start`.

Answer (score 1):

Try killing any process which might have opened the file package.json.

Have you opened the project and package.json from any code editor like VS code ? Close it.

Comment: didnt really understand what you mean

Comment: Do you have package.json in your dir and ar you running npm start from the same dir ?